# set DIV alignment to bottom

Tags: html, css

how can I make `div` **left3 bottom** and **left4 bottom** align to the bottom (like **left2 bottom**) and also stretch **left2 top** `div` over full width?

I tried `vertical-align: bottom;` but it does not help.

cheers,
Pete

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper{
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 940px;
   background-color: #28cf21;
}

.header{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #12bf81;
 }

.left1{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #fc0234;
}

.left2{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #f78325;
}

.left2oben{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f78325;
}

.left2unten{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f11325;
}

.left3{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f78325;
}

.left4{
   float: left;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f78325;
}
body {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   font-size: 90%;
   background-color: #00ccff;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
        header
    </div>
    
    <div class="left1">
        left1
    </div>
    
    <div class="left2">
            <div class="left2oben">
         left2 top
       </div>
        
            <div class="left2unten">
         left2 bottom
       </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="left3">
        left3 bottom
    </div>
    
    <div class="left4">
        left4 bottom
    </div> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "bottom" in css?

```
 .left3{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f78325;
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
}


.wrapper{
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 940px;
   background-color: #28cf21
   Position:relative;
}
```

When both `.left3` and `.left4` are set to `float:left` there will be an issue of the two overlapping. for that you can use different float settings, or use `left` or `right` in css just like we used `bottom`.

**Explanation**

In css, we set `bottom` to 0 for `.left3` and `.left4`, this means the two divs, are 0 pixels from the bottom. The same can be used for `top, right left`.
Position must be set to absolute, in order for this feature to work.

Also, its a good idea to get into the habit of putting a semi-colon at the end of every statement in css, regardless if its the ending statement in the brackets.

**UPDATE**
Set the position for the wrap div to relative, then the position for the inner div to absolute. The positioning means the contents can overlap each other, so you must maintain fixed heights for your content

Comment: I tried it but then the `.left3` and `.left4` are set to bottom of whole page, not inside `.wrapper` `div`

Answer (score 0):

hope it can helped you :)

```
.left3{
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f78325;
   bottom: 0!important;
   position: absolute;

}

.left4{
   float: left;
   width: 220px;
   height: 250px;
   background-color: #f78325;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:38%;
}
```